# Printing two columns with "address cards"

Tags: c#, system.printing

For an application i'm developing as my first c# project, i'd like to be able to print information from the application in a similar style as the 'card style' printing option that's available in outlook.

I've created a User control that is layed out the way i'd like to print it and am able to add that control as often as needed to a form in the two column layout that i want, but so far haven't found a *working* tutorial/example explaining how to print the contents of the form including the visual elements (adding page breaks, without breaking the layout of the user control).

Any advice or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on why you bothered to type "sigh....." but not add something usefull ?

Am I missing something basic, am I approaching this from a wrong angle, did my google skills disappoint you, ... ?